# Read Azure Portal Application Settings of the Static Web App service using Blazor WASM

Tags: azure, configuration, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

I'm running a Blazor WASM application on Azure Static Web App.
In my .NET6 C# application I want to read the setting I added in the portal.
I'm not using nor want to use appsettings.json or web.config. I want to read the value I added in the portal.

I've been reading about this for days now. I found a lot of pages about server-side solutions, which I can't use because I run client-side only.

I assume I need to do something in my program.cs:

```cs
static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, string baseAddress)
{
    services.AddTransient(_ => new HttpClient(new DefaultBrowserOptionsMessageHandler(new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        DefaultBrowserRequestCache = BrowserRequestCache.ForceCache,
        DefaultBrowserRequestMode = BrowserRequestMode.Cors
    })
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress)
    });

    // TODO make the settings from the portal available for all pages and components
}
```

I'm not sure how to inject the settings.

I think I need to use it on my page like so:

```html
@page "/"
@inject IConfiguration _configuration

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<p>Welcome to your new app.</p>
<p>Config: @_configuration["Foo"]</p>
<p>Env: @Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Foo")</p>

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

Please advice.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't find a solution. I'm using a workaround by hard-coding the variables I need based on if I'm in development mode (local) or production mode (published).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, application settings are only available for the backend API associated with your Blazor App (when using azure static web app).

Please refer to [Configure application settings for Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings) for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

As per @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT, application settings are only available to backend API. Basically, the solution is to create a backend(Azure function) that returns the settings to your frontend(Blazor WASM).

The simplest way to implement this is using [Azure Functions is to expose the applications settings using dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection). Using the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings)  makes it pretty straight forward. The options can be injected into a function and returned when called.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you don't want to use appsettings.json, but that was the only way I could read IConfiguration config in a Blazor WASM app.

I use the [Replace Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) in my build pipeline to replace environment-specific values in my appsettings.json.

If you insist on reading the values in the portal, then [Gary Chan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72429301/32598) of building an API to send the config to the client is a way I have seen folks implement.